# pandas groupby & lambda function to return nlargest(2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

Please see pandas df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
            'pay_date': ['Jul1', 'Jul2', 'Jul8', 'Aug5', 'Aug7', 'Aug22'],
             'id_ind': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1]})
```

I am trying to groupby 'id' and 'pay_date'. I only want to keep df['id_ind'].nlargest(2) in the dataframe after grouping by 'id' and 'pay_date'. Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['id', 'pay_date'])['id_ind'].apply(
lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).reset_index()
```

This does not work, as the new df returns all the records. If it worked, 'id'==2 would only appear twice in the df, as there are 3 records and I only want the 2 largest by 'id_ind'.

My desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'pay_date': ['Jul1', 'Jul2', 'Aug5', 'Aug7', 'Aug22'],
         'id_ind': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]})
```

Comment: Yea, it returns the two largest per group, which in this case is all records.  What is your desired output?

Comment: No, look at 'id'==2, there are 3 records in that group.

Comment: Yes.... But you are grouping by `id` *and* `pay_date`, so there are 3 distinct groups with `id == 2`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then. How do I get my desired output then? What I want is to groupby 'id' and take the 2 largest 'id_ind'. But I also want to include the 'pay_date' in the new df as well.

Comment: My desired output: pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
            'pay_date': ['Jul1', 'Jul2', 'Aug5', 'Aug7', 'Aug22'],
             'id_ind': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]}) See updated OP please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort on `id_ind` and doing `groupby.tail`

```
df_final = (df.sort_values('id_ind').groupby('id').tail(2)
                                    .sort_index()
                                    .reset_index(drop=True))

Out[29]:
   id  id_ind pay_date
0   1       1     Jul1
1   1       2     Jul2
2   2       2     Aug5
3   2       3     Aug7
4   3       1    Aug22
```

Comment: This is super clever! Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr.: You're welcome. Happy coding :)